# How to print ********** in a single line by using Debug.Log() in MonoDevelop, a Unity 3D, 2D editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, unity3d-2dtools

I want to print

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

by using a for loop in the console of unity by using Debug.Log() of monoDevelop. Here is my code:

```
for(int row=1;row<=5;row++)
{
  for(int column=1; column<=5;column++)
     {
         Debug.Log("*");
     }
}
```

But it shows the output in this way:

```
*
*
*
*
*
till 25 rows.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Each call to `Debug.Log()` is a new line

If you want to log a line of anything you need to concatenate it into a string, then `Log()` that string.

```
for(int row=1;row<=5;row++)
{
    string str = "";
    for(int column=1; column<=5;column++)
    {
        str += "*";
    }
    Debug.Log(str);
}
```